# How Display categories and subcategories at frontend with sorting alphabetically

Tags: category

I don't have an idea about how can do that
Could you please help me for that?

Comment: which version of magento? Also, if you can explain more about what you want to achieve it will help people answer

Comment: Magento version 2.3.3
I need to sort level1 in the menu by alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this blog.
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Display-all-the-categories-and-sub-categories-in-home-page/td-p/94814

Hope this will help you.
Thanks